# "Вода(,) обогащенная воздухом" - после слова "вода" нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

*Вода(,) обогащенная воздухом* - после слова "вода" нужна запятая?

Answer (score 4):

Запятая нужна, это причастный оборот. НО: обогащенная воздухом вода - запятая не нужна. Причастие стоит перед определяемым словом.